# Memory Leak in initWithContentRect and setContentView

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, memory-leaks

In my application, I am creating a window and setting a content view. Inspector is showing me some memory leaks.

In `setContentView:` I think it releases previous `NSView`.

My code is given below:

```
//contentrect is NSRect which is already initialized.
//stylemask is NSUInteger which is also initialized.
//window_ is of NSWindow type.
window_ = [NSWindow alloc];

//Here, I am getting memory leak.
window_ = [window_ initWithContentRect:contentrect styleMask:stylemask 
        backing:NSBackingStoreBuffered defer:NO];

//Set window delegate to receive close notication.
[window_ setDelegate:delegate_];

//I believe this is the behavior is by default.
//[window_ setReleasedWhenClosed:YES];

//Setting the windows title.
[window_ setTitle:title_];

//Setting the window frame screenrect which is also initialized.
[window_ setFrame:screenrect display:YES animate:YES];

//MyView is inherited from NSView.

//Set MyView instead of default NSView.
//Set as it have same content rectangle.

contentrect = [[window_ contentView] frame];
//Allocate MyView.
MyView * view = [[MyView alloc] initWithFrame:contentrect];


[window_ setContentView:view];


[rWindow orderFront:nil];
```

**Edit:** 
I am not getting memory leak in `setContentView` which I called, but in `setContentView` which is called inside as `initWithContentRect`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to balance `retain`/`release` count

you have to release `window_` somewhere, one place will be in `dealloc`

```
- (void)dealloc
{
    [window_ release]; window_ = nil;
    // other releases
    [super dealloc];
}
```

it is a bad idea to `alloc` `init` in different line

similarly, you have to release your `view` by add `[view release];` after `setContentView`

or `autorelease` it

```
MyView * view = [[[MyView alloc] initWithFrame:contentrect] autorelease];
```

if you have no idea how management works in Objective-C, you better switch to ARC first and learn details about how it works.

Comment: Sorry for the incorrect code. I corrected it. That is `window_` in fact.

Comment: `window_` is nil before this allocation.

Comment: Similarly for this `view`.

Comment: you still have to release `view`